# Validate multiple checkbox groups

Tags: javascript, checkbox, validation

I have 3 groups of checkboxes, checkboxes that belong to the same group have the same name but a different id.
I need to check that at least one checkbox is selected for each group.
I can't write the correct javascript code.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If understood you correctly, this function will do:

```
function checkCheckBoxGroup(groupName) {
  var g = document.getElementsByName(groupName);

  for(var i = 0;i<g.length;i++) {
    if (g[i].checked) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

It returns `false` if no checkbox was checked and `true` if one or more are checked.

You can use this with each group.